# Option to add application launcher to panel "as widget" (not pin) is absent in Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, launcher, panel, 22.04, widgets

There is a difference between pinning an application launcher (to the taskbar) and adding as a widget (to panel): the pinned icon goes away when you open the application, the widget icon stays there separate.

[image]

As far as I can remember in older Plasma both options were available when clicking an application found with the Application Menu and alternatives, but in Kubuntu 22.04, Plasma 5.24.4 the old option "add as widget" is absent.

Can we still add app launchers to the Plasma panel that do not go away when starting the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact it's that not all menu launchers have the option "Add to Panel (widget)", but the default launcher (Kickoff) has it.

I must have used a different launcher that doesn't have it , like Tiled Menu.

---

There is also another way that doesn't involve any launcher:

Open Dolphin file manager at `usr/share/aaplications`, select "Edit - Filter" or Ctrl-I, type the name of the application, then drag and drop the desktop file onto the panel.

[image]

[image]